# Php regex extract email from HTML

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to match pattern from web page.
I want to extract all name and email addresses.
Text is in a HTML table like:

```
Name <email@test.com>
```

Update

```
Name 1 <email1@test.com>
Name 2 <email2@test.com>
Name 3 <email1@test.com>
```

Like this.

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: HTML table like..?

Comment: @Aydin he was missing the spaces so SO removes html

Comment: So all your emails is one email? You need to expand your table so we can see the pattern and also include your expected output. Because I can't see the real problem here.

Comment: First of all, you need to show what you tried already.

Comment: I tried this !<td [a-z0-9_\;/s*]>[a-z0-9_\-\+\<\s]+[a-z0-9_\-\+\<]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z\>]{3})</td>!i but it does not work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Without a clear email pattern you could use something like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2})?
```

Or in code

```
$re = '/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2})?/';
$str = '';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

Where $str is the HTML to parse.

Comment: through this I get the email, but I need the name as well which does not get extracted from this pattern.

Comment: Please paste the actual structure, or a fragment of the actual HTML you are trying to parse, it will be easier to find the pattern and adjust the regex.